# Event Viewer weird HTTP 500

Tags: c#, asp.net

Since some days ago the Event Viewer of my server is showing an error of someone hitting directly the following URL:

```
domain.com:443/page.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=scriptmanager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=;;AjaxControlToolkit
```

This issue is repeated each 1-5 minutes throughout the day.

I recently got rid of all AjaxControlToolkit references in my application, but Event Viewer is still showing the error, so I wonder if it could be a bot who indexed this URL from the HTML code.

How should I manage this situation?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You could use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  It will show the IP address of the computer that is attempting to access the computer along with the error.

Comment: I'm using Cloudflare CDN services, so the IP I that see always belongs to Cloudflare.

This URL should be accesible or should I block it with some kind of redirect?

Comment: I'm not familiar with product.  From web, it looks like it is a firewall that is using Port Forwarding.  Port forwarding should be transparent to to ends of connection.  So if you are seeing the IP of the service then it is doing some validation.  I would talk to people who maintain the firewall to see if the events are normal.